# Overwrite (extend) Validation Error Template

Tags: wpf, binding, localization, material-design-in-xaml

I have a C# MVVM WPF application, which uses [MaterialDesignInXAML](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) Toolkit.
Another Package I'm using in this application is [WPFSharp.Globalizer](https://github.com/rhyous/WPFSharp.Globalizer)

Both packages doing it's job great, but the input in the case of ValidationError is not provided.

So, my idea is to extend the ValidationError Template textbox which presents the error string like it is done without MaterialDesignInXAML. In this extension I would be able to add WPFSharp.Globalizer binding interface and let him doing its job.

TextBoxInput:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
            Width="250" Padding="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
            materialDesign:ValidationAssist.UsePopup="True"
            materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="False"
            materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.PrefixText=""
            materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.SuffixText="{localization:LocalizationBinding LocalizationUnit, FallbackValue=''}" />
```

In an application without MaterialDesignTextBox i would implement Validation.ErrorTemplate which binding to LocalizationBinding from WPFSarp.Globalizer

```
<UserControl x:Class="UsercontrolName"
             ...xmlnsinputs...
             xmlns:localization="clr-namespace:WPFSharp.Globalizer;assembly=WPFSharp.Globalizer_Net6">
    <UserControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                                </Border>
                                <ItemsControl FontWeight="Light" Margin="0 5 0 0"
                                                ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Validation.Errors}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{localization:LocalizationBinding ErrorContent, FallbackValue='undefined localization return value'}" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

specific Question:

How am I able to extend/change/overwrite Validation.ErrorTemplate provided by MaterialDesignInXAML?

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend a template but you can define your own custom one and still keep the `TextBox` style by defining a custom `Style` that is based on the one provided by the material design library:

```
<TextBox
    Width="250" Padding="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
    materialDesign:ValidationAssist.UsePopup="True"
    materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.HasClearButton="False"
    materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.PrefixText=""
    materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.SuffixText="{localization:LocalizationBinding LocalizationUnit, FallbackValue=''}" />
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        ...
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: @Daimonion: Did you try this?